# Animate mesh so it's parts appear from left to right

Tags: animation

How can I **animate** a **mesh** to appear from left to right. Example: You have a dog and you want the tail to appear first and eventually get to the head (the head doesen't show up until the end). Thanks! :D (In the image you see frames of what my animation would be with a basic dog made of cubes).[image]

Comment: Hello, your question is a bit vague, could you please illustrate?

Comment: Hey!, I apologize. I added some images to illustrate. (In the image you see frames of what my animation would be with a basic dog made of cubes). I want my animation to start just with the back part of my dog and eventually draw the rest of the dog from left to right.

Comment: it depends on the kind of effect you want, you can either use Boolean or Build modifier, Build modifier is different in the sense that it will make faces appear one by one as if you were building the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to do it: With a ***Boolean*** modifier or with a ***Build*** modifier.

You could use a ***Boolean*** modifier (*Difference* mode). It looks like you'll avoid bugs if your boolean object (my cube) is a bit subdivided:

[image]

To make the cube transparent in *Solid* mode, choose *Viewport Display > Wire*, to make it invisible in *Render*, disable all its *Ray Visibility* options.

[image]

For a different kind of effect you could use the ***Build*** modifier, it will make your object gradually appear, face by face, as if you were building it:

- Model your object, in *Edit* mode put the 3D cursor on its tail:

[image]

- Select all, in the *Mesh* menu > *Sort Elements > Cursor Distance*. It will sort the vertices from the tail to the head.

[image]

- Give your object a *Build* modifier, play with the parameters so that the object appears gradually. You can animate with some keyframes on these values.

[image]

Comment: Woah, I really don't know how to thank you, this is a very elaborate answer and you took the time and even sent screenshots. Thank You so so much, if you need anything let me know.

Comment: Woah, I really don't know how to thank you, this is a very elaborate answer and you took the time and even sent screenshots (it worked by the way! I am using the first option you said). Thank You so so much, if you need anything please let me know.

Comment: great, you're welcome  ;)